# Insert value to binary tree root in C

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

Im a beginner in C programming and im trying to do a binary tree c library.

heres my binary tree struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Noeud
{
    int valeur ;
    struct Noeud* gauche ;
    struct Noeud* droit ;
};

typedef struct Noeud TNoeud;
typedef struct Noeud* TArbre;
```

Heres the way I create it

```
TArbre NouvelArbreVide( void )
{
    return NULL;
}
```

However i would wonder on how to put a value to the root of the tree like

```
TArbre NouvelArbreVide(int value_root)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

that would put the value_root value to the binary tree root.Im not sure on how to do that even though its probably very basic.

thank you

Comment: You're going to have to at least pass the tree in to `NouvelArbreVide`. Or wait, did you just want to initialize it with the value?

Comment: yes initialize it with the value(value to the "root" of the tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start your tree with a single node, you want to allocate a new root like this:

```
TArbre NouvelArbreVide(int value_root)
{
    TArbre newRoot = malloc(sizeof(TNoeud));
    if (newRoot)
    {
        newRoot->valeur = value_root;
        newRoot->gauche = NULL;
        newRoot->droit = NULL;
    }

    return newRoot;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was trying to figure

Comment: With that, will I be able to save the root value somewhere? i mean for example if I add elements to the tree,will I be later on able to display the value_root element? If not is there a way to store it in a variable or something to be able to use it later on? thanks

Comment: You have to keep the result around as your root. Just do `TArbre theRoot = NouvelArbreVide(42);` and make sure you keep `theRoot` around.

Comment: this returns me error error: expected ';' before 'theRoot'| I added that line in my main.c test program wich create the binary tree with the (ex:42) value

Comment: Well, move `TArbre theRoot;` to alongside your other declarations and then `theRoot = NouvelArbreVide(42);`.